# How to detect when the Internet connection was lost - WinINet - C++

Tags: c++, wininet

My ++ program connects to my FTP server and does some stuff which takes about 10 minutes. I want that when the connection is lost, the program waits until the connection is back then resumes. Here's the code I made (incomplete, please read comments):

```
#include <WinINet.h> //and other headers
HINTERNET hIntSession;
HINTERNET hFtpSession;
using namespace std;

void ResetConnection() {
    if (hIntSession != NULL) InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession); //Do I need to add this line?
    do {
        if ((hIntSession = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0)) == NULL) continue;
        hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hIntSession, "x.example.com", 21, "user", "pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
        if (hFtpSession == NULL) {
            InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession); continue;
        }
    } while (FALSE);

}

int main() {
    ResetConnection();

    /*
    FTP stuff
    if(is not connected) ResetConnection();

    FTP stuff
    if(is not connected) ResetConnection();

    and so on ...
    */

    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
}
```

Also, I don't want to use extra memory, so maybe I should add more of "InternetCloseHandle()" function.

Please do not ask me to install a third party library.

Comment: FTP uses TCP, which already has recovery logic. If the situation is so bad that TCP fails, the sanest recovery may be to restart FTP from the beginning. The FTP server probably cannot recover in the same way as your program. Note that HTTP servers generally do have better support for recovery.

Comment: @MSalters I'm talking about when the client PC running this program gets disconnected from the Internet. In this case, the ResetConnection() function (defined in my script above) should be called. If the FTP server fails: by the time I restart the FTP server, the client PC should be in the while loop until the FTP server is fine. Otherwise the client will keep failing execution of the FTP stuff terminate.